# Changing a specific div opacity changes the whole tags inside it

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

I am having a problem with my css sheet. I have a background image and a form in the center of the image. I wrapped the form in a div "box" and gave it a background color to make the form more elegant and visible.

It all worked great, but I have a little problem; when I set the opacity of the div "box" to 0.5 the whole form takes the same opacity.

Here is my css style

```
body
{
padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
background: url('/images/university.jpg') #f2f2f2 no-repeat left top;
}
legend
{
font-size: 2em;
}
form
{
opacity: 1 !important;
}
.Box
{
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 25px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is my HTML page. I am using Laravel's Blade engine:

```
@extends('design')

@include('partials._nav')

@section('middle')

<div class="Box">

{!! Form::open() !!}

<fieldset>

<legend>Create Account :</legend>

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::text('Username', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Username']) !!}
</div><!-- /form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password']) !!}
</div><!-- /form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::password('psw', ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Re-type Password']) !!}
</div><!-- /form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::submit('Create Account', ['class'=>'form-control btn btn-       primary']) !!}
</div><!-- /form-group -->

</fieldset>

{!! Form::close() !!}

</div>

@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Opacity by default is inherited by all children in the parent container.

What you can do is

- make your image semi-transparent yourself with an editor.
- add a div next to the children, add background to it and after making it semi-transparent, position it behind mentioned children.

Something like

```
div {
  width: ###px;
  height: ###px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```